# Code for updating the each element(binary) of array on the basis of majority voting of past 5 elements(including that element also)

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have an issue in writing a code for a problem related to the element updation of an array based on the majority voting of its past 5 elements including the element itself.

Explanation: Suppose we have an array having elements in binary form. arr= [0 , 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1 , 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]

Now, according to our problem, we have to find the majority value of the past 5 elements including the number itself. So for the first 4 elements, the new updated value would be Zero, and then the value at the 4th index will be based on the majority voting of past elements that is [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]. So the majority value for index 4 is '0' as the count of '0' is greater than the count of '1' in a given window. Similarly, we have to do the same for all the elements.

input arr= [**0 , 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1 , 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1**]

Output arr=**[0 , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0**]

Comment: Why is the index 8 `1` because until index 8, there are 5 zeroes and 4 ones. Shouldn't it be `0`?

Comment: @AnshumaanMishra for 8th index, we have past 5 elements including value at index 8th is  [0, 1, 0, 1 , 1] , so here majority is of '1' that's why  updated value of index 8 is '1'

Comment: @VishalRaj then you can just check if the sum of the past 5 elements is >=3 (11 in binary). If it is, change it to 1 else to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
arr = [0 , 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1 , 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
out = [int(sum(arr[max(i-5, 0):i]) >= 3) for i in range(1, len(arr)+1)]
print(out)

# Output
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Variation:

```
out = [int(sum(arr[max(i-4, 0):i+1]) >= 3) for i in range(len(arr))]
```